# Accessing elements of a table row on the basis of checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage, I have a table in which there's a radio button for each row. The name of radio buttons is the same for all rows to access them as a group. I have a button which alerts the row number whose radio button is checked. I'd like to access individual elements of the table of that row as well. Any thoughts as top how I might be able to achieve this would be very welcome.

Here's a Fiddle for the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gz668/13/

On the click of the button "edireq", it currently alerts the row number whose radio button is checked. I'd like to access the values of other fields of the table (requestor, approver, status etc. too.)
Here's the jquery code

```
$("#edireq")
    .button()
    .click(function () {
    var ele = document.getElementsByName('reqradio');
    var len = ele.length;
    var flag = -1;
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (ele[j].checked) {
            flag = j;
        }
    }
    if (flag > -1) {
        alert("Row : " + (flag + 1));
    } else {
        alert("Select a row first");
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an odd mix of native javascript and jQuery. You can use the `:checked` selector to get the chosen radio button, then get the closest `tr` and read the `text` of each `td` within that row. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reqtablenew tr').click(function () {
        $('#reqtablenew tr').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active").find('input[name="reqradio"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
    $("#edireq").button().click(function () {
        var $ele = $('input[name="reqradio"]:checked');

        if ($ele.length) {
            var $tds = $ele.closest('tr').find('td');
            var id = $tds.eq(1).text();
            var requestor = $tds.eq(2).text();
            // and so on..

            alert(id);            
            alert(requestor);
        }
        else {
            alert("Select a row first");
        }
    });
```

});

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz668/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = ["Req id","Requestor","Approver","Status","Product","Version","Source","Destination"]; //list of title
if (flag > -1) {            
    $(".active").find("td:gt(0)").each(function(i){                
        console.log(list[i]+": "+$(this).text());
    });
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz668/15/)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gz668/16/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("table").on("click", "tr", function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", true);
});
$("#edireq").on("click", function(){
    activeRow=$(".active");
    cells=activeRow.children();
    if(cells.length >0){
    row={
        select:cells[0],
        requestId:cells[1],
        requestor:cells[2],
        approver:cells[3],
        status:cells[4],
        product:cells[5],
        version:cells[5],
        source:cells[6],
        destination:cells[7]
    };
        alert(row.requestor.textContent);
    }
})
```

});